# screen corruption on lenovo 4446 laptop

Tags: compiz, laptop, screen, lenovo, screen-corruption

After my Lenovo laptop has been on for a while, I get screen corruption starting to appear. Sometimes I have to restart the X server before it goes away, sometimes it goes away by itself. The corruption looks like scrambled pixels and it occurred both in 11.04 and 11.10.

Anybody else seen this and knows what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this problem is due to compositing (either Compiz in Unity or Mutter in Gnome Shell). If you switch to Unity 2D or Gnome Classic, the problem should go away. Of course, this doesn't help too much if you want the visual effects present in the full versions.

Comment: Wierd; I have just noticed that if I alt-tab, I don't get the normal flashy alt-tab screen that attempts to show the contents of windows - it just looks more like the old windows one. I am running gnome-classic in 11.10 but there must be some kind of compositing enabled due to the fancy alt-tab that it normally has. I wonder if the fact the alt-tab has changed is indicative of the compositing going tits-up.